# R: svm from e1071 predictions differ based on "probability" argument setting

Tags: r, svm

Under certain circumstances, there are differences in predictions from e1071 package svm models depending on the setting of the `probability` input argument. This code example:

```
rm(list = ls())
data(iris)
## Training and testing subsets
set.seed(73)  # For reproducibility
ri = sample(seq(1, nrow(iris)), round(nrow(iris)*0.8))
train = iris[ri, ]
test  = iris[-ri,]
## Models and predictions with probability setting F or T
set.seed(42)  # Just to exclude that randomness in algorithm itself is the cause
m1 <- svm(Species ~ ., data = train, probability = F)
pred1 = predict(m1, newdata = test, probability = F)
set.seed(42)  # Just to exclude that randomness in algorithm itself is the cause
m2 <- svm(Species ~ ., data = train, probability = T)
pred2 = predict(m2, newdata = test, probability = T)
## Accuracy
acc1 = sum(test$Species == pred1)/nrow(iris)
acc2 = sum(test$Species == pred2)/nrow(iris)
```

will give
acc1 = 0.18666...
acc2 = 0.19333...

My conclusion is that `svm()` performs calculations differently based on the setting of the probability parameter.
Is that correct?
If so, why and how does it differ?
I haven't seen anything about this in the docs for the package or function.

The reason I bother with this is that I have found the performance of the classification to be not only different, but consistently slightly worse when `probability = T` in a project where I do classification based on ~800 observations of ~250 gene abundances (bioinformatics stuff). The code from that project contains data cleaning and uses cross-validation, making it a bit bulky to include here, so you'll have to take my word for it.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: @hmhensen I disagree. That question simply asks what the primary function of the probability argument is, which is to output probabilities or not. It does not show that the predictions of svm changes based on that argument or ask any of the questions asked above. Neither is any of the answers to said questions included in any of the answers or comments.
Would you like me to clarify anything in the question? If so, which part is not clear?

Comment: Wasn't sure if you thought that question went far enough so wanted to bring your attention to it. Removed the possible duplicate comment.